# Is it necessary to get The Memoir Pages?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I'm in sequence - 4 ( I think that I am in S-4) ,   and want to start collecting the DNA Fragments / The Memoir Pages , I was browsing through the Internet and found that people got in the Hagia Sophia without doing anything in particular. But I can't find the Hagia Sophia , so is it necessary to get the memoir pages ??

Comment: Necessary for what? Completing the story? No. Getting all Achievements/Trophies? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

The Memoir Pages are a collectible as many others. They count towards the side objectives and are therefore required for 100% synchronization; nevertheless they do not provide an ingame benefit. So feel free to collect them once you have beaten the game and decide you want to complete it fully.

Answer (score 0):

The memoir pages unlock the Hagia Sophia level. Once you have all ten pages, a new icon will appear on your map, and that is how you get into the Hagia Sophia.

If you complete the Hagia Sophia level, you are rewarded with the Ishak Pasha armor. This is the strongest armor in the game. (Stats are equal to those of the Master Assassin armor).

None of this is required to complete the game, but I believe it is required for 100% sync: the Hagia Sophia level has "100% sync" requirement. (You have to finish it in 6 or 8 minutes, IIRC).